# What powers do the ribbons possess?

Tags: the-wolf-among-us

After playing through the game I didn't fully understand the mechanics of the ribbon.  Could someone help explain exactly how it works and what powers it has?

> I believe Vivian had the original ribbon, which had a power that would kill you (through beheading) when removed.  The ribbon was cloned, and was the reason why Faith and Lily died (i.e. had their ribbon removed).  The magic mirror refuses to see Faith in episode one due to other powers.  Nerissa walks away at the end of the game still wearing the ribbon, refusing to have it removed.

Beyond these facts, there are other elements of the story that I either missed or falsely assumed were true regarding the ribbon's powers.

My actual assumptions:

> - The ribbon stops the owner from lying
>  - The ribbon stops the mirror from seeing Faith (not sure if you can use the mirror to see Nerissa, Vivian or Lily)
>  - Removing the original ribbon removes the curse for its clones

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spoilers:

> The original purple ribbon was worn by Vivian. The ribbon's curse prevented Vivian from talking about it and would kill her if it was removed. This lead to her husband trying to remove it and Vivian leaving him. Her story can be unlocked in the [Book of Fables](http://fables.wikia.com/wiki/Vivian's_Story)
>
>  Googling suggests that Vivian's ribbon is loosely based on [The Red Ribbon](http://people.howstuffworks.com/culture-traditions/holidays-halloween/scary-stories10.htm).
>
>  The Ribbon copies were created by Georgie so the girls at the Puddin' & Pie would maintain client confidentiality. As well as not being able to talk about the ribbons, the girls cannot talk about their work. This meant, for example, that Ichabod Crane could indulge his Snow White fetish with Lilly and Lilly couldn't tell anyone about it (or blackmail Crane over it). The ribbon also stopped Nerissa telling Bigby about Faith's murder.
>
>   While it is never discussed, one can also assume that the ribbon would prevent its wearer from writing things down instead of talking about them.
>
>   When the original ribbon was removed from Vivian, the curse on the other ribbons was broken. This meant that Nerissa was able to tell the town about The Crooked Man.
>  
>  Regarding scrying on Faith with the mirror, there are several theories (some of which don't even involve the ribbon). Most are just speculation though.